# How to change inode size on EXT2 file

Tags: linux, scripting, filesystems, inode, ext2

I am running Ubuntu on my MacBook Pro as I need to reformat a hard drive to EXT2 with iNode size of 128 to use for DCP delivery.

Comment: I assume you mean a USB-connected drive or such? Do you know how identify the correct device name for it?

Comment: Yes I know how to identify the device path for the USB connected hard drive.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo mke2fs -t ext2 -I 128 -L DCP123 /dev/sdb1
```